# Recurrence relation for strange sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I am comfortable with the recurrence relations for the Fibonacci series and for binary search, but I don't know how to find the recurrence relation for this algorithm:

```
Algorithm strange-sort(A[0,,,,,,n-1])
       if n=2 and A[0]>A[1]
       {
              swap(a[0],a[1])
       }
       else if n>2
       {
              m=ceiling(2n/3)
              strange-sort(A[0.....m-1])
              strange-sort(A[n-m......n-1])
              strange-sort(A[0......m-1]) 
       }
```

How would I get a recurrence relation for this algorithm? What does it solve to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Stooge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) algorithm. Wikipedia says that the runtime is O(n<sup>log 3 / log 1.5</sup>), and by coming up with the right recurrence we can see why.

Notice that each recursive call does O(1) work and then make three recursive calls of size 2n / 3. This gives us the recurrence relation

> T(n) = 3T(2n / 3) + O(1)

We can now use the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to solve this. Here, a = 3, b = 3/2, and d = 0. Since log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>1.5</sub> 3 > 0, by the Master Theorem this solves to O(n<sup>log<sub>1.5</sub> 3</sup>). Using properties of logarithms, this rearranges to O(n<sup>log 3 / log 1.5</sup>), which is about O(n<sup>2.70951129135...</sup>).

Hope this helps!